# Playing sound even when phone is in silent/ DONOT disturb mode

Tags: android

I have a use case where i want to play sound even when the phone is in silent mode on API level > 23. After a bit of googling i found that i should explicitly ask the permission from user to do so. Now the permission is all set using following code.

```
private void requestForDoNotDisturbPermissionOrSetDoNotDisturbForApi23AndUp() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Open Setting screen to ask for permisssion
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult( intent, ON_DO_NOT_DISTURB_CALLBACK_CODE );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The sound is also played in silent mode using media player after adjusting the volume.

```
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(stream, deviceLocalVolume,
            AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Once played the sound is reset to original sound volume. But i see that the phone is no longer in *donotdisturb* mode. Why so?

EDIT: Detailed code:

```
void playSound(int stream) {
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    int deviceLocalVolume = getDeviceVolume(volume,
            mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(stream));

    Log.d(TAG,
            "device max volume =  "
                    + mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(stream)
                    + " for streamType " + stream);
    Log.d(TAG, "playing sound " + uri.toString()
            + " with device local volume " + deviceLocalVolume);

    oldVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(stream);
    Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "setting device local volume to "
            + deviceLocalVolume);
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(stream, deviceLocalVolume,
            AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    golbalMMediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;

    try {
        final OnPreparedListener OnPreparedListener = new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OnPreparedListener prepared.Actually playing music now");
                mp.start();
                countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(maxTime * 1000,
                        tickTime * 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "tick while playing sound ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "timer finished");
                        resetVolume();
                        stopPlaying();
                    }
                };
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        };

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context.getApplicationContext(), uri);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(stream);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(OnPreparedListener);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Done playing music now");
                resetVolume();
                Log.d(TAG, "releasing mediaplayer now");
                try {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(Constants.APP_TAG,
                            "error on oncompletion listener", ex);
                }
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
}

private static int getDeviceVolume(int currentVolume, int deviceMaxVolume) {
    return (int) Math.ceil((deviceMaxVolume * currentVolume) / 100);
}

private static void resetVolume() {
    try {
        Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "reseting volume to " + oldVolume
                + " for stream = " + stream);
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(stream, oldVolume,
                AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("error", "error", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to switch the DnD back on:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.setNotificationPolicy(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
```

see [INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE):

> All notifications are suppressed except those that match the priority criteria.
>
> Some audio streams are muted.

Comment: Moving the phone from DND to NonNDN and then to DND sounds bad as it might also give other apps chance to play some sounds which might not go well with user. I just want my app to play sound.

Comment: @user93796 since you use `AudioManager` to produce the sitution, you probably have to also use it to switch back the `AudioManager` with `ADJUST_MUTE` and `RINGER_MODE_SILENT`. or the `NotificationManager`  with`INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE` / `INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY`. my answer does not disable DnD - which actually has a real function for some people; playing sound there might be bothersome. Play Store policies might even discourage or forbid this... when not even the phone application is allowed to do so.

Comment: I added the detailed code in new edit. What i really want to do is , play notification sound even when phone is in silent mode. And not affect other apps or phones DND mode even temporary. Is there some way?

Comment: if it wakes up from DnD as soon as it plays the sound - the only way is to switch it back mute, as already outlined in my answer. but somehow it falls below: https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/ ...hence it is not respecting the user's wish not to be disturbed, at least unless having an explicit confirmation from the user to do so (with default disabled).

Comment: That is fine. How does alarm clock work then? Alarm clock apps also plays sound when phone is in DND mode. And i dont think that it temporarily changes the phone from DND to non DND and then back to DND.

Comment: @user93796 that might be `STREAM_ALARM` ...while you might not be playing the sound through `STREAM_NOTIFICATION` but through `STREAM_MUSIC`. possibly it would not wake up when using `STREAM_NOTIFICATION` (in case it even plays there). there are not too many possibilities and that's the only alternative I could think of, in order to not produce the undesired behavior in the first place.

Comment: STREAM_ALARM was the thing i was looking for. It suits my use case. But the issue is when i pass STREAM_ALARM sometimes i can hear sound and sometime i cant. If i set looping to true  i can hear the sound always after some times. May be the issue is not so obvious with looping as even if am not able to hear sounds for first few loops i can hear it for later. Any idea? I stongly doubt crescendo effect.

Answer (score 0):

The given sample could help you.

For Api_level <= 21.

```
 val soundPool by lazy {
     SoundPool.Builder()
        .setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)// EVEN IF THE SOUND IS LOWER, THIS CONFIGURATION PLAYS FULL VOLUME.
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build())
        .build()
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buzzer)
 
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.play_btn).setOnClickListener {
      //  mediaPlayer.start()
        val soundId: Int = soundPool.load(this@BuzzerActivity, R.raw.triangle, 1)
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener { soundPools, i, i2 ->
            soundPools.play(soundId, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1f)
        }

    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    soundPool.release()
   // mediaPlayer.release()
}
```